# How to use data from updated DOM

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I am able to upload files with the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add-new-document').fileupload({
        url: '/add.php?id='+$('#add-new-doc').data('id')+'&type='+$('#new-doc-type option:selected').val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: true,
        ...
```

but if I select something different on `#new-document-type` or change the value of data-id in `#add-new-document` and click on `#add-new-document` the values input are not the updated values.

How do get it to input the values from the updated DOM?

Comment: The object you are passing into `.fileupload` is set when the document is loaded. It will never change during the lifecycle of the page.
Assuming `data-id` would change during the lifecycle of the app, you'd need to create the object (or just the .url prop) when ever you need an updated `.url` (more source code and we'll prob be able to help you with examples).

Comment: So I should set `.fileupload` inside a `.change` for `#new-doc-type`? OK. I will try that.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks.